# Simple Netty Echo Server/Client not receiving messages

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, netty

I'm trying to write a simple echo server with Netty. I'm reading [Netty in Action MEAP v8](http://www.manning.com/maurer/) to get down some theory and learn the core basics of Netty. The client connects successfully, but no messages get through from the client. I am able to telnet a message to the server and receive the response, so I guess the issue is on the client, I just have no idea what is wrong, due to me being new to Netty.

Here is the client:

```
public class Client {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                          .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
                          .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                              @Override
                              public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                  ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
                              }
                          });

            ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }


    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        new Client("127.0.0.1", 11235).start();
    }
}
```

And the Client handler: (I did try appending '\r\n' to the sent message, but that did not make a difference, which I found here: [Netty Client to Server message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923032/netty-client-to-server-message))

```
@Sharable 
public class EchoClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
        ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Netty MAY rock!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
                "Client received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

    }

    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

The server:

```
public class EchoServer {

    private final int port;

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                        System.out.println("New client connected: " + ch.localAddress());

                                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoServerHandler());
                                    }
                                });
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        new EchoServer(11235).start();
    }
}
```

The server handler:

```
@Sharable
public class EchoServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println(
            "Server received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        ctx.write(in);
    }

    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
            .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

It must be something small I'm missing, so any help will preserve my fleeting sanity and will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `write` use `writeAndFlush` in your ClientHandler:

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("Connected");
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Netty MAY rock!", CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! And @NormanMaurer RESPECT to Mr Author, waiting in suspense for the next update!