# If I want to pass my invoking class some information, what is the best way to do this?

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently working on a small chat and I am currently facing some difficulty on how to fetch some data from one client and distribute it to the others.

This is my Server so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try 
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);

        Hashtable<String, Client> connectedClients = new Hashtable<String, Client>();

        while (true)
        {                                               
            Socket s = server.accept();             
            System.out.println("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName());   

            Client chat = new Client(s);


            Thread t = new Thread(chat);
            t.start();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("An error occured.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is the class Client:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        String newLine = null;

        while (true)
        {
            newLine = in.nextLine();



            if(clientName==null){
                clientName = newLine;
            }
            else{
                out.println(clientName+":  "+newLine);
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(clientName+" disconnected.");
    }   
}
```

(Note that I only added really crucial passages). As you can see, I am creating a new thread for each client, which takes the first sent string as a Username. This is being dealt with by my GUI, by disabling all message fields until a Username is set, so that's working already.

However, as you might have noticed, there is an unused Hashtable which should be filled with a String and a Client. As you could have guessed, this is going to be the Username and the Client instance.

Now the problem here is, how to get the data from the Thread class to the calling Server class.

2 ideas I came up with:

- 1) Make the Thread Observable and add the needed methods to my Server class. As soon as a name is set, it will notify my Server class, add the String and the notifying class to my Hashtable, and then distribute it amongst other clients.
- 2) Add a static method to my Server, which does the same thing.

However, I feel that I'm thinking too far out of the box here. I am pretty sure there is an easier way around this, but I just can't figure out.

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

Comment: You should have a `Server` object, which contains the collection. Right now, you're just placing all the server components in the main method. If you encapsulated the collection in an object, you could then pass that object to every `Client` instance

Comment: I think, It's better to use something ready than building from scratch, I recommend to use Netty framework, you will find simple example about chatting application here in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923032/netty-client-to-server-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your collection in an object, then pass that object to each client with methods needed to perform the actions needed on that collection.

For example:

```
class ClientManager {
    private Hashtable<String, Client> clientMap = new Hashtable<>();

    public void sendGlobalMessage(String message) {
        for(Client client : clientMap.values()) {
            if(client != null) {
                client.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now pass this to every client. Your `Client` class should look something like this, accepting a `ClientManager` as well as providing a `sendMessage` method:

```
class Client {
    private ClientManager manager;
    private Socket socket;

    private DataOutputStream out;

    public Client(ClientManager manager, Socket socket) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            clientManager.sendGlobalMessage("hey!");
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(message);
    }
}
```

When your `Server` accepts a connection, it creates a `Client` object. This is when you should pass it:

```
class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(...)) {
            ChatManager manager = new ChatManager();

            while(true) {
                Client client = new Client(manager, ss.accept());
                new Thread(client).start();
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `Server` object (if it's not in `main`) to each instance of `Client` and use that reference to maintain the `Hashtable`.

If you don't ever create a `Server` object, then you will need to use your second option (which is not that far out of the box, really).  Just make `connectedClients` a `static` member of your `Server` class, and add another static method to maintain it.

You may want to consider making that method `synchronized` (unless that's the reason you're using `Hashtable` instead of `HashMap`, for the synchronization).

Comment: You should avoid static when possible. It introduces global state which is not only hard to test, but can lead to code that's harder to manage (not being aware of what is accessing that static value). Check out my answer, where I pass each client the collection. This way, you know only Client instances and the Server have access to the collection

Comment: @VinceEmigh: I guess I misunderstood exactly what the OP was trying to accomplish.  My first suggestion, though, was (in a nutshell) similar enough to what you recommended: passing a common object to each `Client` and using that to maintain the list (in my suggestion) or to actually broadcast the message (in your example).  About using `static` -  I was responding to an option the OP asked about, not recommending it. But thanks for the BP (Best Practice) rule.